# IOException when Impersonating User

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, impersonation

I am getting a very strange error when I am Impersonating an user in my WPF application.

My application is basically a TabControl in a Window with two tabs.  On one tab, the one that shows at startup, I have a graph.  On the other tab, I have a handful of controls used to set up the graph.  In particular, I have two ListView controls (or derivations thereof).  In the MenuBar, I have a MenuItem that a user uses to logon as a different user, and I am using WindowsImpersonation for this.

Here's the problem:  If I start the program, then, before clicking anything else, I click on the Login menu item and successfully login, then I click on the second tab, I get an IOException with the message "The directory name is invalid".  Here is the top of the Call Stack:

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
at System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName(Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
at System.Windows.Input.Cursor.LoadFromStream(Stream cursorStream)
at System.Windows.Input.Cursor..ctor(Stream cursorStream)
at System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumnHeader.GetCursor(Int32 cursorID)
at System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumnHeader.get_SplitCursor()
at System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumnHeader.HookupGripperEvents()
at System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumnHeader.OnApplyTemplate()
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.GridViewHeaderRowPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
...
(The rest of the stack is a bunch of Measure methods and Event handlers up until I get to the Threading and Application methods.)
```

It looks like the program is having trouble finding the file that contains the cursor information for the GridViewColumnHeader.  NOTE: I am not using any kind of special cursor, just the standard Windows ones; although I do have events attached to the GridViewColumnHeader.

This error isn't thrown if I first click on the second tab, then login, nor if I click on the second tab, click back on the first tab, then login. So, there is obviously something wrong with how I am communicating with the rendering engine.

In my internet searching, I have only encountered one other person to encounter something similar to this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fb648b6-2e4f-47da-91fd-a6fefd7e5462/impersonate-in-wpf-c-throws-the-directory-name-is-invalid-exception?forum=csharpgeneral, and there was no real answer to the problem.

I'm sure I could get around this by "selecting" the second tab in the code-behind and re-selecting the first tab.  However, I would prefer to handle this without being too hackish.

Any suggestions or insight?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you find a minimal example and post it?

Comment: The issue seems to be with Path.GetTempFileName() .  I think the minimal example that Fabian H. requested should be a call to Path.GetTempFileName() while impersonating.

Comment: I am not calling that function directly.  The failure appears to be taking place during the actual rendering of a ListView.  Based on the way the stack reads, it looks like the app cannot find the directory where the cursor resides.  However, there are no special cursors being used, so why Windows can't find the Windows cursor directory is beyond me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I could figure out a minimal example for this, and since this app is in the final stages of debugging before going into production, I don't think it's worth the time at the moment. Selecting the other tab in the code-behind works, so I am going with that.